# Server side session management in GWTP

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

Hello I am using GWTP for my application development. In the application I am in need to server side session instance to put some data in that session instance. I saw some examples of GWT where there is Action class which extends ActionSupport class. 
There are some method in the examples through which we can have the server side session instance.Like below :

```
public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
        return ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    }

public HttpServletResponse getResponse() {
    return ServletActionContext.getResponse();
}

public HttpSession getSession() {
    HttpSession session = getRequest().getSession();
    return session;
}
```

But I am not getting the similar thing in GWTP. Please help me out. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is there any way we can make this constructor free of the arguments and still get the references to Request, Response, Session etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got some thing which is helping me.I am sharing this here.

```
private Provider<HttpServletRequest> requestProvider;
private ServletContext servletContext;


@Inject
public LoginCallerActionHandler(
        Provider<HttpServletRequest> requestProvider,
        ServletContext servletContext) {
    super();
    this.requestProvider = requestProvider;
    this.servletContext = servletContext;
}
```

Here is my action handler class.In which i can use session.

```
servletContext.setAttribute(SessionKeys.LOGGEDIN_USER.toString(), returnObject.getLoggedInUser());
```

Comment: Hello Sanjay, I am facing the same problem as yours. In your answer by using `servletContext.setAttribute`, you are putting user info into `ServletContext` and not in `HttpSession`? As servlet context is per "web application" this data you have to remove manually. What if user never logs out!

Comment: If user never log out then we had timer or auto log out in case if user is inactive for more than 5 mins...at that time we make a call to remove all the acquired information...hope this will answer ur query.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring or Guice on your server side you can get Request/Response injected into your Action. For example, if your are using GWTP's [DispatchServletModule](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStartedDispatch#Setting_up_server), you can use features of Guice's [ServletModule](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/servlet/ServletModule.html) as:

> DispatchServletModule extends Guice ServletModule and maps request
>   URLs to handler classes.

Here's an example from [Guice wiki](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule#Available_Injections):

```
@RequestScoped
class SomeNonServletPojo {

  @Inject
  SomeNonServletPojo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) {
    ...
  }

}
```

I am not sure if GWTP binds the handlers in Singleton scope or not. If it does bind it in singleton you should inject a Provider instead.